# SQLite - How to support query result as a parameter in user defined functions

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have created a custom C++ function and added it to the SQLite db connection by means of the sqlite3_create_function method. It works if I supply it direct values:

```
eg. select myfunc(col1) from table1
```

However, the sqlite3_prepare_v2() returns an error code of 1 when I attempt to have it take a query result as a parameter:

```
eg. select myfunc(col1, (select col2 from table2)) from table1.
```

Comment: Does your function have one or two parameters?

Comment: It does take 2 parameters.

Comment: Really? Why does it then work with one parameter? Anyway, call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).